# How to change content of UIPicker without creating a new one?

Tags: swift, uipicker

I am a complete newbie in Swift, so excuse me if it may be a dumb question.
I am trying to implement a way so that the content in the picker changes depending on which button is clicked. 
For example, let say there are two buttons "Months" and "Years".
If I click Months button, I want a picker to appear with all it's content. But once I click Years button, I would like the same picker to appear with all the years instead (vice versa).

Is there a way to do this without creating a new UIPicker?

I tried creating a boolean flag to change some return values for pickerView functions, but it wouldn't work.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**

Update all the array that your `UIPickerView` is using for display

**Step2:**

Simply call `yourPickerView.reloadAllComponents()`